# jQuery callback function executed but not when expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function with callback. the function renders a canvas to div then the callback hides the canvas. I dont think i am doing this correct becuase the callback is executing before the function has completed i.e the callback hides the canvas(#a), but it is hiding canvas before it completes the render to the div.

```
$('#sl').on('mouseup', function(){

        canvas=document.getElementById("a");
        ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('.s').find('img').attr('src', dataURL);

    },callback);    

     function callback(){
         $('#a').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are wrong here.

Firstly, why are you using `getElementById` if you're using jQuery? Seems counterintuitive. If you're using jQuery, stick to it.

Secondly, what's the point of the callback just to have the element hide?

Here's how I would do it.

```
$('#sl').on('mouseup', function(){
  const $canvas = $('#a')[0];
  const ctx = $canvas.getContext("2d");
  const dataURL = $canvas.toDataURL();

  $('.s').find('img').attr('src', dataURL);
  $('#a').hide();
});
```

Disclaimer, this code is untested, it's based on what you provided.

Comment: i started out doing it all in a singe function  but issue is  the canvas is hidden before it has written to div so there is a blank div for a split second and then the image appears in the div. i.e the canvas hides before image is copied and appears in the div. i want the image to display in the div then hide the canvas. so i wanted to make it a callback so the canvas hides once the write to div is complete.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your usage of `on` method is wrong. According to the the jQuery documentation of `on` method:

`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

this method accepts event type, optionally selector or data and a handler/callback - in that specific order. In your case you pass selector and two functions which is wrong. When passed 3 arguments `on` method thinks that the last one is an actual callback you want to call when event occurs. And what your code does when `mouseup` event occurs is hiding element with `#a` selector. Correct implementation would be:

```
$('#sl').on('mouseup', function(){
    canvas=document.getElementById("a");
    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $('.s').find('img').attr('src', dataURL);
    $('#a').hide();
});
```

Comment: i started out with exactly what you have. but the canvas is hidden before it has written to div so there is a blank div for a split second. so i wanted to make it a callback so the canvas hides once the write to div is complete.

Comment: @russ I don't understand :)

Comment: #a is the canvas that contains an image. the mouseup event copies that image to <div class="s">. after the data has been copied to the div i.e the image is now in the div, the canvas is then hidden. problem is that the canvas is hidden before the image has been copied to the div.

Comment: perhaps the operation of copying image is slower and canvas is hiding before it completes. try to add some timeout to hiding with `setTimeout` to check if it's true.

Comment: yes, this is the issue. this is why i wanted a callback function :) so it executes only after copying image is complete.

Comment: yes, thanx. it works now but i would prefer to do it with a callback. how would i do this with a callback?